# add dynamic empty objects to an array React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code, which basically adds empty objects to an array.

```
  handleAddNewRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rowData: [
        { MEMBER: "", ALIAS: "", STATUS: "" },
        ...this.state.rowData
      ]
    })
}
```

Lets say, I am passing an integer value to the function `handleAddNewRow` and then it dynamically adds the number of empty objects to the array based on the integer value, How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at my function:

```
handleAddNewRow = (number) => {
   this.setState({
       rowData: [
            ...this.state.rowData,
            ...(new Array(number).fill({ MEMBER: "", ALIAS: "", STATUS: "" }))
       ]
   });
}
```

Comment: it does not work. It only adds 1 empty object.

Comment: I've tested on devtool and it works as well. Can you give me a code so I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

in the following code i wrote code in simple condition
change it on your own

```
const array = [{name: '', family: ''}]
function a(num, arr) {
  let temp = [...arr, {name: '', family: ''}]
  if (num - 1 > 0) {
    temp = a(num - 1, temp)
  }
return temp
}
const b = a(4, array)
console.log(b)
```